# Mysql slow on windows, fast on linux. Why?

Tags: mysql, jpa

I have installed a SpringMVC Web application with JPA and a Mysql Database.
The application is displaying statistics from the database (with a lot of selects)

It works quite fast on Linux(mysql 5.5.54), but it is very slow on Windows 10 (mysql 5.6.38).

Do you know what could cause such a behaviour on Windows?
Or could you give me hints or tell me where to search?

**[UPDATE]**
**Linux :** Intel® Core™ i7-4510U CPU @ 2.00GHz × 4  / 8GoRAM
**Windows :** Intel Xeon CPU E31220 3.1Ghz  4GoRAM

I know that the windows machine is not as "powerful" than the linux one. I wonder if, by increasing the memory, that could be enough. Or does Mysql needs a lot of CPU too.

Comment: About the "_I wonder if, by increasing the memory, that could be enough_", just need to check the perfs during the execution, you can see what is used on both machine and see what is blocking. But to do a comparison, you need the same version of every tools on both (if possible) and be sure to have the same data ... (if one DB have 1/10 of data, this can't run the same)

Comment: I have tested on another windows machine which has 6Go Ram and mysql 5.5.47, the query is fast (0.750s) compare to the windows machine with 4go Ram (4s). I guess that mysql uses mainly memory to perform this query? Both have the same database.

Answer (score 0):

My list would be:

1. Check configs are identical - not just the settings in my.ini - values not set here are set at compile time and the 2 instances have definitely been compiled seperately! You'll need to capture and compare the output of [SHOW VARIABLES](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-variables.html)
2. Check file deployment is similar - whether innodb is configured to use one file per table, whether the files are distributed across multiple disks
3. Check adequate memory available for caching on MSWindows
4. disable anti-virus
5. Make sure MSWindows is configured as a server (prioritize background tasks)
6. Windows sucks, deal with it :)